# Getting problems with JFileChooser and getAbsolutePath() in Java

Tags: java

I am getting some problems reading a file.txt using JFileChooser, I use this to get the path from my directory and catch it in a String to use then later into a new FileReader("Path Here");.

```
JFileChooser buscador = new JFileChooser();
buscador.showOpenDialog(buscador);

String  RutaProxy = buscador.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(RutaProxy);
```

**Output**

```
C:\Users\Silver\Desktop\Multivisitor\Lista de proxy aqui.txt
```

I use that Route in a FileReader because in that File.txt i wanna read a list of proxy, something like this:

```
String RutaProxy = buscador.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(RutaProxy));
```

Here i am getting Error because java only let me use path like this into the
new FileReader(C:/Users/Silver/Desktop/Multivisitor/Lista de proxy aqui.txt);

```
C:/Users/Silver/Desktop/Multivisitor/Lista de proxy aqui.txt
```

And not:

```
C:\Users\Silver\Desktop\Multivisitor\Lista de proxy aqui.txt
```

How can I do to get a Path With this "/" not with this "\"?

I dont know if someone know what I mean.

Comment: just saying ..you can pass a file directly to filereader.
 `new FileReader(buscador.getSelectedFile())`

Comment: sorry i did not understand your answer, you can explain me more detailed?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: when i choose a file.txt using JFileChooser and use that Route Path in new FileReader(C:\Users\Silver\Desktop\Multivisitor\Lista de proxy aqui.txt);  and eclipse told me that java cant use this simbol "\" in the route path, how can i get a route path from a JFileChooser like this: C:/Users/Silver/Desktop/Multivisitor/Lista de proxy aqui.txt?

Comment: You can replace the '\' s in `RutaProxy` string with '/' s. 

`String replacedPath = RutaProxy.replace("\", "/")`;

And pass `replacedPath` to the file reader.

Comment: That was a good idea but when i use RutaProxy.replace("\", "/"); simply java dont me use this simbol "\", trown Error Instanly. another solution?

Comment: @LeoGalindo actually you can only get this error by hard-coding the path string inside the FileReader consturctor. This is because the symbol '\' is used to escape characters inside strings and the compiler will complain it as a end of string error. If you pass the path as a variable (like you have done) it won't give any errors!

If you want to hardcode it just add an extra '\' like this

`"C:\\your\\path\\should\\look\\like\\this.txt"`

Comment: If you really want to replace "\" s with "/" s use this instead of the method I have above. `String replace = RutaProxy.replace("\\", "/");`

Answer (score 0):

The anwser that told me @tibzon was a successful :D Thanks a lot man!! this is the correct way to change the path:

```
C:\Users\Silver\Desktop\Multivisitor\Lista de proxy aqui.txt
```

in:

```
C:/Users/Silver/Desktop/Multivisitor/Lista de proxy aqui.txt
```

With this line code:

```
    JFileChooser buscador = new JFileChooser ();
                // here capture in a String the Path route from file selected
                String  RutaProxy = buscador.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

                //then Replace String RutaProxy with:
                String replacedPath = RutaProxy.replace("\\", "/");

                // and here print 
                    System.out.println(replacedPath);
```

And the OutPut this time was this:

```
C:/Users/Silver/Desktop/Multivisitor/Lista de proxy aqui.txt
```

@bitzon Thank you so much man :D and the other users too for reply :)

Comment: this tell me that i can do it in 2 day, but i will come back again and put like answered ;)